# Missing Windows Form Templates in newly Installed Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015

[image: Missing Windows Form Templates]

Good Day Everyone. Above is the image of the templates I have in my newly installed Visual Studio 2015. I installed it yesterday and noticed that some templates are missing. Specifically Windows Form. I don't know why it became like this.

What do you think is the reason behind this? And what should I do. Thanks.

Comment: Related post - [No templates in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41189398/465053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close **Visual Studio**
2. Open "**visual studio command prompt**" and run the command:

   `devenv /installvstemplates`

[Source](https://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/missing-templates-in-visual-studio-installed-templates/)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and solved it by installing the "C++/CLI support" under the Desktop Development with C++.

#### Steps:

- 1: click on New Project in Visual Studio 2017
- 2: click on "Open Visual Studio Installer" which is right above the Name field box
- 3: when the installer opens, click on "Desktop Development with C++" on the right-hand side.
  [image: Step 3]
- 4: check the "C++/CLI support"
  [image: Step 4]
- 5: Close down Visual Studio 2017
- 6: click the Modify button at the bottom left.
  [image: Step 6]
- 7: Re-launch VS when it is done.
- 8: if all has gone right, you should have access to windows forms in c#
  [image: What it should look like]

The reason may be due to Windows Forms running on a C++ framework.  Without the C++/CLI Support installed, the Windows Forms might not run.