# Can only add database, text file or xml file to ASP.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, project

So I'm running into this problem with my Visual Studio project.
I'm trying to add a new simple class to my project. I'm pretty sure this is the way to do it.

[image: Trying to add a file.]

So whenever I click `New Item`, this menu pops up:

[image: What I see when I try to add a new class]

I can't seem to add anything other than those files. Changing tabs doesn't help. All of them are empty, except for the data tab, which contains The Sql Server Database, XML File and XML Schema. The general tab contains the Text File option.

Any help from you guys is appriciated!

Comment: What version of Visual Studio you are using?

Comment: @DrewAguirre I'm using 2017. But I fixed my problem, I just have to wait 2 days to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my files were stored in the `App_Data` folder that had been automatically generated. It apprears to be meant for data storage and not logic.

If you have the same problem, move your files to e.g. a `Helpers` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add the file upon clicking Add option, there is a class option here:

[image]

Regarding additional templates, you can refer to this link for solution:

[no templates in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189398/no-templates-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: That also brought me to the same options, But I figured it out.