# Visual Studio 2017 c++ win32 console project template

Tags: c++, console-application, visual-studio-2017, project-template

I am on Visual Studio Community 2017 v. 15.3.1 and I can't seem to find Win32 console application or Win32 project. Still have empty c++ project template and Windows Console Application template.
On the start page, I still have win 32 console project available, but if I click it, [I get a prompt about removing it from the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2X9K.png)

EDIT: I have currently installed following Workloads:

- Universal Windows Platform
- Net desktop development
- Desktop development with C++
- Game Development with C++
- Visual Studio extensions development
  I've done no changes to workload configuration, save from adding a few extra components.

I've been fiddling with installer for a while but can't figure out which package I need for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you installed C++? It doesn't come with VS by default.

Comment: For me they are called "Windows Console Application" and "Windows Desktop Application". Seems somewhat reasonable to not call them Win32 when building for 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @NeilButterworth yes, sorry, I updated my question with installed workloads.

Answer (score 22):

The new updated changed some things. Go to file -> new project -> visual c++ -> windows desktop -> windows desktop wizard -> select whatever you want

If you haven't installed C++ at all (doesn't come by default as mentioned above) look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189398/no-templates-in-visual-studio-2017?rq=1)

Comment: Seems like the change went completely under my radar. Thanks for pointing this bit out to me.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. Credit all goes to the original website! :)
(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/93159/cant-find-win32-console-application-for-new-projec.html )

If you are using Visual Studio 2017, and can't find "win32 console project" after File ->> New ->> Project:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrfYo.jpg : VS 2017 "New Project" without "win32 console project" )

Go to File ->> New ->> Project ->> Windows Desktop Wizard ->> select "Empty Project"

VISUAL STUDIO 2015
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLsHp.jpg : File ->> New ->> Project ->> "Win32 Console Application")

VISUAL STUDIO 2017
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydEVU.jpg : File ->> New ->> Project ->> "Windows Desktop Wizard")

Comment: I think this is a didactical answer, but it looks quite a lot like a question. Would you like to rephrase?

Comment: Thanks for nicely pointing it out. Wasn't really expecting anyone to notice. 

Hope this helps.

Comment: Much better. Now it looks definitly like an answer, with added good style for giving credit. Sorry that I lack actual expertise in the matter and therefor cannot meaningfully judge the content. Good luck.

Comment: Woah really appreciate it. Thanks! All the best on your end as well! :)

Comment: It can be accepted by OP, if it is the best help. But if not, it might still be upvoted just for being a good answer. No need to delete just because OP does not choose this solution. If the answer is judged (by others) to actually be bad in one way or another, you will see downvotes. Then deleting is to be considered.

Comment: Without content expertise, I can recommend to extend the explanation of what the pictures show.