# Win32 Console Application missing in VS2017. How to create C++ Empty Project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I installed the `VS2017 community` and I am lost: the Win32 Console Application in missing.

I don't even have template when I go to `New Project` and also I cannot create C++ Empty Project in `VS2017`.

How I can solve it?

Comment: ***the win32 console application in missing*** You probably did not install the c++ compiler. I believe that is an option that is turned off by default.

Comment: Go to your add/remove programs and 'modify' your installation to include the c++ options

Comment: The Win32 template was renamed, so it's possible that's what you're running into. See this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785786/visual-studio-2017-c-win32-console-project-template

Comment: @drescherjm I think i marked the c++ compiler when i was installing the VS, but I will check it again

Answer (score 15):

Install all the optional tools for c++ development

then follow these steps ( Microsoft has updated its visual studio and there are some minor changes)

The new updated changed some things. Win32 Console Application is gone in the new update. Go to File -> New Project -> Visual C++ -> Windows Desktop -> [Windows Desktop Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icpgy.jpg) -> Application type: Console Application (.exe), Additional Options: Empty Project

Then have fun!

Comment: Any idea why it takes so much longer to do so ?

Comment: @user7468879: on my PC it takes a couple of seconds to create an empty project.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to install "Visual Studio C++ core features". Don't install everything about C++. It consumes too much storage and possibly slow down your IDE.

Steps:

- Open Visual Studio 2017 Installer.
- Select "Individual Components" tab.
- Select "Visual Studio C++ core features".

That's all.

If you are not interested in Game or Mobile C++ development you can remove your selections in "Workloads" tab to get free space in your hard drive :)