# How do you create a manifest file?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, io, admin

I have looked everywhere for answers to my problem but no one has one so I am asking myself.

How do you create a manifest file in visual studio.

I have seen everywhere to add item and then choose application manifest file. but that is not there when i try add item.

I hope someone can help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the menu at the top: Project -> Add New Item...

In the list, you should find Application Manifest File. If it isn't there, be sure you are selected on "Visual C# Items" in the tree view on the left.

Comment: There is no Visual C# items its just Installed and online If you wanna see example picture of what i have i uploaded it here https://ibb.co/kK3JYy

Comment: Do you need to install them? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189398/no-templates-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: I have installed all.

Comment: From your image, you are trying to add an item to the solution. You need to add it to the project instead. Try right-clicking on the Project (in bold) ->Add -> New Item...

Comment: Thank you so much that worked perfectly