# Missing web template under visual C# in newly installed Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm specifically looking for asp.net MVC 4/5 template under Visual C#. Already installed .NET framework component but still not seeing the web template as I see before in my VS 2013. Please help.

Comment: At this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189398/no-templates-in-visual-studio-2017/41189472#41189472?newreg=e51c9e118da742969d05992aac339e98]
I think I need to install some components under Web & Cloud section...

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Installer - Workloads tab, under Web & Cloud, select ASP.NET and web development. You can now add the usual ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework).

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qaNT.png)