# VS2017 New Project Tree - Templates and Installed Languages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have two questions:

1. Why is C# listed as "other language"?
2. Where is the "templates" folder?

[image]

I'm looking for the template folder to create a "Blank App (Windows Universal).  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189398/no-templates-in-visual-studio-2017) shows VS2017 with a templates folder.

Comment: Did you select Visual Basic as the primary language when you installed it? The templates are in Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates

Comment: Check also under `Other Project Types`

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't think I did.  I even re-installed to double check, but don't seem to have the option to select anymore.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya That just shows "Visual Studio Solutions>Blank Solution".

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem by resetting to default settings

[image]

and selecting "General" here:

[image]