# (asp.net) MVC Template is missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I searched for more than an hour but it seems that the MVC template is missing
This is normally what I need to have: 
[Screenshot with MVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Q6I.png)

But here's what I really have : 
[MVC Missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ0sc.png)

How I can fix it ?
Thank you.

**This isn't a duplicate with ([Missing MVC template in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015)) :** 
Web developer tools **is no longer present** on version 2017 of visual studio.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the selected packages in Visual Studio Installer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing MVC template in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613505/missing-mvc-template-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: The screenshot : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSVJG.png

Comment: If you read down the possible duplicate answers, you will find one with 30+ useful flags that explains the template appears only when you select a particular project type.

Comment: Even if I select Web Form or all the particular projet type, MVC is still missing.
_(In the Web category, I only have "ASP.NET Web Application" without MVC obviously :/)_

Comment: Can you tell us the menu entries you select in order to get to the dialog box in your snapshot? e.g. `File > New > Project >Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)`

Comment: This might help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189398/no-templates-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: New > Project > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Application (I only have this choice available)

Comment: _In C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\ > I don't have MVC_
And the custom templates folder is empty.. What's wrong ?

Comment: Is there a `1033` folder in the `Web` folder? I would suggest uninstalling the ASP.NET and Web Development workload and reinstalling it again.

Comment: Yes, there is three folder in `1033` : WebApplicationProject40, WebTemplate45, WebTemplateCloud45. Yes, I'll will try, thank you anyway

Comment: Those are the templates that you need. Apparently they are not being read. Uninstall and reinstall ASP.NET and Web Development workload.

Comment: I found ! I analyzed the logs and there is an error with some asp.net packages. I don't know how I can fix it but that the pastbin of errors : https://pastebin.com/sMrHGUf7

Comment: It looks like it's failing to install IIS Express: `IIS Express 8.0 or higher is not installed.`. Long story short, it looks like you had other versions of Visual Studio installed in your machine and that is causing problems. Check this out: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24464/packageidmicrosoftancmiisexpressmsipackageactionin.html

Comment: @ASmallCookie: Any luck? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is how I solved my problem :**

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\` and delete all
2. **Delete (Uninstall) `IIS Express 8.0`** and reboot your computer

And then, start Visual Studio Installer, and choose repair (It's going to take an hour. 
It's a bug I think, but the problem was ***IIS Express 8.0***

*(Thank JuanR)*

Comment: I did something similar and it fixed a different issue.  I can now load ".deployproj" projects but I still cannot create them (still no template).

Comment: I don't have a "Web" folder in CSharp

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get all the templates by performing the below steps.

1) Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\common7\iDE\ProjectTemplates\csharp\web\1033\WebTemplateCloud45

2) Double click the WebTemplateCloud.vstemplate file and that brought me all the templates.