# Why CPP Project templates don't appear in visual studio 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, project-template

Installed the latest version of VS2022 with the workload ***desktop development with c++*** (Accepted all default settings and checkboxes)
, The downloading and installation were completed successfully.
[image]

When I launched visual studio 2022 to create a new project, there are no CPP project templates as you can see, reinstalling and repairing didn't help, How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No templates in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46895353/16764520)

Comment: For those still figuring out, I've tried the above comment, and it worked for VS 2022. I'm reposting that url from Minxin Yu above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46895353/16764520

Answer (score 1):

I copied the **VC** folder from

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates

to

> C:\Users<user>\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates\ProjectTemplates

and restarted the Visual Studio. Now I see all the C++ project templates.

Answer (score -3):

This solves my problem C++ Project templates don't appear in visual studio 2022?

1. Make sure Visual Studio is up to date.
2. Open Visual Studio Installer. Press more and then repair.
3. You should be able to see the template once it finishes.

Comment: OP already mentioned: " reinstalling and repairing didn't help" So how do you think your answer is helpful?