# Visual Studio 2022 Missing Template for Form (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, templates, visual-studio-2022

Running Visual Studio 17.2.3.  I've got a solution that consists of many projects built against.Net5.  I've suddenly lost the ability to add forms to dependent projects.  If I try to add a new form to a project, the "Form (Windows Forms)" template does not display when clicking on "Add->New Item..." for the selected sub-project.  However, if I select the project set as the "startup project" and click on "Add->New Item...", the Form template does appear.

I've tried using the solution indicated in "[Missing Windows Form Templates in newly Installed Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958217/missing-windows-form-templates-in-newly-installed-visual-studio-2015)" in particular, running 'devenv /Intalltemplates" but it did nothing.

**UPDATE**: June 9 - I added a new project to the solution.  I noticed that when adding a new item to the new project, it did display "*Form (Windows Forms)*" as a template.  I also noticed a difference in the dependent frameworks.  The projects that show the form template all contain a dependency on "**Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms**".  Is there any way to add this dependency?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127718/how-do-i-add-features-to-visual-studio-2017), is for a more recent VS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  However, I ran a Modify with the Installer and the template still does not appear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After looking into my update above, I found that the following flag was missing from the projects that no longer allowed for adding a Form to the project:

```
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

I'm not sure why the flag was removed.  Once I added the above flag to the affected projects, "Forms" then reappeared as a template.

I started to notice the problem after I had updated Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.2.3.  I'm not sure if that is related.

Comment: Works for me. I'm just wondering why it compiles and runs just fine without this setting.

Comment: Thanks! It was confused as to why WPF was the only form type offered, don't want to go down that rabbit hole, changing one line in the csproj file and now I can add a simpler to use form (windows form) that I'm more used to. In my case it was a fresh install of Visual Studio 2022 v17.9.2.